# Will a browser make the AJAX if window.location is changed immediately

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, window.location

I have the following scenario

```
<script>
   jQuery.ajax{
       url : 'some serverside bookkeeping handler',
       type : post,
       data : ajaxData
   };

   window.location = 'Some new URL';
</script>
```

**Use Case** : I want to do a bookkeeping of how many times a particular link on a web page  is clicked. Note that the landing page is not owned by me. I was thinking to making an ajax call and simultaneously navigating to the new URL.

I am basically wondering if any browser would not even make the ajax call and navigated to the new URL. My assumption is that the browser could still be in the process of preparing the ajax request object and navigating to the new URL made the browser to not fire the ajax request.

Can there be such cases?

Note that I am not worried if the ajax response is in error.

Answer (score 2):

to be on a save way put your redirect into a success handler of the ajax call !

```
jQuery.ajax{
   url : 'some serverside bookkeeping handler',
   type : post,
   data : ajaxData
   success: function(){   window.location = 'Some new URL'; }
};
```

or use `<a href="some url" target="_blank" ></a>` to open a new tab in the browser if you can.

Comment: Thanks john. But this would add extra latency on the client side which we cannot afford.

Comment: maybe try websockets

Answer (score 1):

seems like it is impossible. The `window.location` line executed before ajax response reurns.  When `window.location` changes, all the ajax requests from the previous domain are canceled. Try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vfk3S/8/ and look at "Network" tab in devtool.

Comment: Thanks lxgreen, The ajax call is cancelled but does that mean the browser does not even made the request? I am actually looking whether there exists a case where the browser was not even able to make a request.

Comment: The best and the most reliable way to test it is to catch the requests on the server side.